# proxy.conf file for http and websockets on same endpoint

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have a working dev environment where I proxy http requests to a django server running on my backend/laptop using a proxy.conf.json file:

```
{
    "/graphql": {
        "target": "https://localhost:443/graphql",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

I run the npm server using this proxy file (above).

Now I need to setup websockets on the same endpoint (/graphql) and I am not sure how I can define two different rules for the same endpoint - one each for https and ws, based on the requested protocol.

I think I may need to do this using javascript instead, but not sure how to proceed. Any help/pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that all I needed was to specify `"ws": true` in the proxy file. I was concerned that I needed to determine the protocol (ws vs http) and then conditionally (a) change the target protocol (ws vs http) and (b) change the ws option to true for websockets based on the incoming request.

But it turns out that the http connection is upgraded to ws as soon as you specify `"ws": true`, so nothing else is needed. And I needed to drop the endpoint in the target as well. The final file that worked for me was:

```
{
    "/graphql": {
        "target": "https://localhost:443",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "ws": true
    }
}
```

So no javascript was required.